# default path for package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm configuring node and npm in a new computer, it seemed to worked fine but I can not run npm install.

I cloned my project and opened it. Then from path (which contains package.json file):

```
C:\Users\myUser\projects\myProject
```

I run:

```
npm install
```

but I have an error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\myUser/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\myUser\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-16T05_38_38_166Z-debug-0.log
```

what can be wrong with the configuration? I want the typical behaviour where it searches for the file in the current path.

Comment: make sure current direcotory is `C:\Users\myUser\projects\myProject`. run `cd C:\Users\myUser\projects\myProject` then `npm install`

Comment: this is the current directory

Comment: Run `cd`, what does it say? What does that log file say?

Comment: seems npm is confused about OS. because its using forward slash `/` instead of backward slash   in path (`npm ERR! path C:\Users\myUser/package.json`), idk why

Comment: @bogdanoff that's just standard path-munging. It's not relevant